# Make 2 forms (Quote / Enrollment) work like an "Add to Cart" experience

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have a "Quote" form where the user selects a State, Manufacturer and Model from three SELECT inputs.  There are 2 pricing columns that are associated with each Manufacturer that I need the values to show on screen when they hit "Add Device" (Submit Button).

If they are happy with the Quote, they will hit "Enroll Now".  Besides needing the prices to show, I need those options they selected to populate the same fields on the Enroll form on a different page.

Here is my controller...

```
function action_mfr_data(){
      $db = \Database::connection('esco_web_connection');
      $quoteData = $db->GetAll('SELECT DISTINCT wpp_MfrName FROM Products_Premiums ORDER BY wpp_MfrName');
      echo '<option value="">Select Manufacturer</option>';
      foreach($quoteData as $data){
         echo '<option value="'.$data['wpp_MfrName'].'">'.$data['wpp_MfrName'].'</option>';
      }
      die();
   }

   function action_mdl_data(){
      $db = \Database::connection('esco_web_connection');
      $quoteData = $db->GetAll('SELECT DISTINCT wpp_Model FROM Products_Premiums where wpp_MfrName= ?  ORDER BY wpp_Model', array($_POST['manufacture']));


      echo '<option value="">Select Model</option>';
      foreach($quoteData as $data){
         echo '<option value="'.$data['wpp_Model'].'">'.$data['wpp_Model'].'</option>';
      }
      die();
   }

   function action_annual_data(){
      $db = \Database::connection('esco_web_connection');
      $quoteData = $db->GetAll('SELECT DISTINCT wpp_StateDefaultAnnual FROM Products_Premiums where wpp_MfrName= ?', array($_POST['annual']));


      //echo '<option value="">Annual Price</option>';
      foreach($quoteData as $data){
         echo '<div>'.$data['wpp_StateDefaultAnnual'].'</div>';
      }

      die();
   }

And here is my AJAX in the view..


    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('[name="select_manufacturer"]').addClass("disabled");
    $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "<?php echo $this->action('mfr_data')?>",

              success: function(result) {
         $('[name="select_manufacturer"]').html(result).removeClass("disabled");

              }
          });

        });

     $('[name="select_manufacturer"]').change(function() {
          var manufacture = $(this).val();
          $('[name="select_model"]').addClass("disabled");
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "<?php echo $this->action('mdl_data')?>",
              data: 'manufacture=' + manufacture,
              success: function(result) {
        $('[name="select_model"]').html(result).removeClass("disabled");

               }
          });


      });

      $(document).ready(function () {  
          var annual = $(this).val();
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "<?php echo $this->action('annual_data')?>",
              data: 'annual=' + annual,
              success: function(result) {
                 console.log('in annual success');
                 //console.log($result);
                 //alert(result);

              }
          });
  });
</script>

Can someone help me get those values to show and to follow through to the other form PLEASE!?
```